# What is the difference between mounted and unmounted filters?

Tags: photography

I'd like to know more about filter wheels and filters, but don't know the difference between these types. Can anyone explain (ideally with images)?

Comment: What is the context? Where are you seeing these terms?

Comment: @PeterErwin Building a telescope. It seems mounted filters are those with a metal cylinder around them, with threads so they can be screwed in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unmounted filters are just the bare filters which are designed to be put into slots in filter wheels (which have square or round recessed slots in them to hold filters). Mounted filters have a metal rim around them which holds (and slightly protects the edge of the filters) and typically have screw threads on them to enable them to be screwed into eyepieces.
The image below shows one of Las Cumbres Observatory's  14 position filter wheel that holds 2inch/50mm round filters.  [image: Image of filter wheel holding mounted and unmounted filters] This wheel is holding both mounted filters (in the right/top right quadrant) and unmounted filters in the remainder of the wheel. Here is a closeup of one of the mounted filters:
[image: Image of a mounted filter]